# File occurance check with Abbrevia in Delphi 10.1

Tags: delphi, abbrevia

I am trying to check a zip file content(drag and dropped) for a specific file and I am using a method like below;

```
procedure TForm1.DropTarget1Dropped(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
  var i:Integer;
begin
AbZipKit1.FileName := Data.Files[0];
if AbZipKit1.FindFile('readme.txt')>0 then showmessage(‘exists’) else
  begin
   showmessage(‘non-exists’);
end;
end;
```

For that purpose I’ve created 2 zip files and added two txt files (readme.txt and test.txt) in both. But to first file: I’ve added “readme.txt” file first than “test.txt”. To second one I’ve added “test.txt” than “readme.txt”. I mean I’ve changed the order of file adding.

After dropping first file, program shows a message as “exists” but for second file “non-exists”. I think FindFile method search for only first file of zip content. Is there any correct way of searching for a file without caring the order?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindFile` returns the index of the file. Either 0 or 1 for the scenario you describe. So testing `>0` is wrong. If the target file is the first in the ZIP container then its index is `0`.

An index of `-1` is returned when the file is not found. So replace `>0` with `<> - 1`.

Comment: Good to see david save your day , that's what david do always :)

Comment: A bit of debugging would have helped too, but it seems that many developers lack this skill nowadays...